# Obtain covariance of pose estimation from ORB-SLAM2

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, geometry-msgs, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am trying to fuse pose estimation data obtained from ORB-SLAM2 with IMU data using the [robot_localization](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization) package.

However, this package requires the pose estimation to be provided according to the [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html) message type. I know how to obtain the pose estimation from ORB-SLAM, is there a way to get the covariance that corresponds to this pose estimation?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335084/obtain-covariance-of-pose-estimation-from-orb-slam2/) by [mmunster](https://answers.ros.org/users/46938/mmunster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmunster](https://answers.ros.org/users/46938/mmunster/) on 2019-10-10**:
Thanks for the answer! In that case I'll indeed use trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ORB-SLAM doesn't provide covariance, for such case you will have to try hit and trial

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1